# Around as metaphorical

Tags: prepositions

Can "around" be used in a sentence such as:

"They created awareness around accessibility"

It seems to me to be somewhat too vernacular to be in a written text.

Comment: Can you make a full sentence to reveal accessibility of what?

Comment: Earlier in their careers they created awareness around accessibility by revealing their own negotiations with it in white cube art spaces.

Comment: Can you include this in your original sentence in the question?

Comment: I'd probably use ***of*** rather than ***around*** in this context (metaphorically accessible *art*, as opposed to the literal provision of disabled access to art shows or whatever), but it's entirely a matter of personal style & preference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is valid, particularly for spoken English, and probably for the technical context that I am assuming this came from.

For formal/written English one would probably use 'of', 'concerning' or 'regarding' in preference.